# AsyncTask not working on 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-asynctask, compatibility

I created a class below which goes to internet and sends a request to php script. I created it like `AsyncTask` and not in main thread in order to work on 4.0.4, but when I test it, it doesn't work, although it works fine on 2.2. Do you know what is the problem?

```
class download extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String s1, String s2) {
            String result = "";
            //http post

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Vreme", s1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Datum", s2));

            InputStream is = null;
            try {

                String adresa = "http://senzori.open.telekom.rs/script.php";
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(adresa);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            //convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably not working because you have overloaded doInBackground, but not called the overloaded method.

Change it so the original method is like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    return doInBackground (params[0], params[1]);
}
```

Note that it now makes the overload useless, move the code back into the overriden `doInBackground (String... params)`, and you also need to make sure that when you call `execute()`, you supply two Strings as the arguments.

Comment: Whatever `d2` is supposed to be, I don't know your full implementation :). That's also probably the other reason why the overload failed. If you passed 2 strings on 2.2 but only 1 passed on 4.0.4, you default to the first, blank method.

Comment: @Vladimir so is your issue resolved? Some input would be helpful.